# About (DDR2) RAM

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, upgrade

I remember hearing this a lot: "You can't have 4 GB and 2 GB sticks of RAM, or 8-4. Only 4-4, 2-2, 8-8 etc." you got the point. My 2-year-old laptop is dead about a month now and I'm using my old one which has DDR2 RAM. I opened it to clean it, and I've noticed something weird. It has 3GB of RAM in total. One stick with 2GB and another one with 1GB.

I have to tell you at this point that, the last time it had an issue we sent it to the company for a service, so those are the guys who made this upgrade to the RAM (this was about 6-7 years ago).

So, is it eventually possible for a laptop to have different sticks of RAM? Because jugding by that, I'm ready to get another 4GB stick and put it with the 2GB stick to make it 6GB in total, because it doesn't seem to be an issue at all. I have had this laptop 10 years now with no serious issues, and the last 7 years has this upgrade to the RAM. So, is it going to harm the system if I put a 4GB stick together with the 2GB (which I already have) to make it 6GB?

It's a Fujitsu Amilo Pi3560 (came with Windows 7, but now has Windows 10) and it's a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can have mixed memory in your system as long as your system supports it and the timing is the same. The only problem is that in order for dual channel memory to be working, the memory sticks must have identical sizes.

So mixing 2+2gb gives you 4gb of memory in dual channel mode, but mixing 2+1gb gives you 3gb of memory in single channel mode. Its a lot slower, but it does work.

One thing you need to keep in mind, is timing. If you add sticks with different timings, the system can become unstable.

Some advice about upgrading: if your laptop is not running a 64bit OS only 3,5GB of ram will be addressable. Upgrading to 6GB will not be wise unless you have a 64-bit processor and are planning to do a clean windows install too.

Speedwise, 2x2 GB of ram will outperform 2+4gb ram if you don't use many programs. But 6GB in single channel ram will outperform 4gb in dual channel ram if you still use a lot of ram and thus have to use the swapfile a lot

Comment: The laptop is a Fujitsu Amilo Pi3560 with 64-bit OS. Back then came with Windows 7, and after it I installed Windows 10. Before a month when I started to use it again, I made a fresh install of Windows 10 20H2 and put an ssd on it. The next steps is to put the HDD on the caddy and put 6GB of ram now that I know it is possible! The only thing I don't understand is the "timing" thing. Do you mean the mHz? If you mean this, my rams are 800 mHz each.

Comment: Yes, and also the CAS Latency. Each RAM has a timing as in CL14-14-14-34. See also: https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/cas-latency-ram-cl-timings-glossary-definition,6011.html